# One of my pdf files in my apache server can be accessed the other can't, with the same permissions and same directory

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd

I have two pdf files in my server:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 apache apache 1422861 Sep 11  2014 file1.pdf
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 apache apache  340815 Aug 27 13:06 file2.pdf
```

I can access the first one by going to **www.myserver.com/pdffiles/file1.pdf**

I just uploaded the second one and changed permissions to apache:apache and rwxr-xr-x so I wouldn't have problems with permissions, but when I try to access the second file with **www.myserver.com/pdffiles/file2.pdf** I get this:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access
>   /pdffiles/file2.pdf on this
>   server.

What am I missing?

**I got the following on my ssl_error_log:**

> [Thu Aug 27 13:30:46.755295 2015] [core:error] [pid 3025]
>   (13)Permission denied: [client x.x.x.x:60230] AH00132: file
>   permissions deny server access: /var/www/myserver/file2.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't know the problem was SELinux but I discovered that was the problem because I turned it off with `setenforce 0` and then it worked. 
This is how it looked when I listed the files with `ls -alZ`

```
-rwxr-xr-x. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 file1.pdf
-rwxr-xr-x. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 file2.pdf
```

so I fixed it with:

```
chcon unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 file2.pdf
```

and also I turned SELinux back on with `setenforce 1`.

Comment: Any sort of ACL would be fairly high on the list of suspects, as would immutability if it was a write problem.